# How to set a value of List object into another List object?

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

I have one POJO. Let's call it `TrackingDetailDto`. Here the member variables of this POJO.

```
OrderDto orderDto;
private String awbNumber;
LogisticProviderServicesDto logisticProviderServicesDto;
List<TrackingHistoryDto> history;
```

So in `TrackingDetailDto`, I have another list object called "history". I would like to add several values that I got from the database.

```
 List<LogisticTrackingDetailDto> trackingDetaillist = new ArrayList<LogisticTrackingDetailDto>( logisticTrackingDetailList.size() );
 List<TrackingHistoryDto> historyList = new ArrayList<TrackingHistoryDto>(logisticTrackingDetailList.size());
```

I do some setter operation for each list object. And success. The question is, how to add `historyList` to `trackingDetaillist` in this list object (`List<TrackingHistoryDto> history`)?

Comment: 1. Use DTO all-caps, as it's an acronym; 2. Where is the variable of `TrackingDetailDto`?; 3. If you need, you can easily have a `List<List<T>>` type e.g. *List of the Lists of T*.

Comment: What is `TrackingDetailDto` and what is `LogisticTrackingDetailDto` ? Are they the same?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri, for me an acronym like *DTO* is a word itself, so I would write it in camelCase as OP does. Because when you have a list of DTOs you might want to name it `myDtoList` which is easier to read than `myDTOList` ...but maybe it's just me :)

Comment: @GameDroids yes, it's just you. Acronyms are way easier to read with they're all capitals, besides that's the syntax of how to write acronyms. Imagine you have a `ObjectControllerWithDtoParser` class, is this really easy to read here? I don't think so.

Comment: @GameDroids I'm sorry, yes they are same.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a simple lists concatenation?

```
trackingDetaillist.getHistory().addAll(historyList)
```

**UPDATE**

As [GameDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/896249/gamedroids) has mentioned in the comments, you might need to iterate over the list of trackingDetails:

```
trackingDetaillist.forEach(detail -> detail.getHistory().addAll(historyList))
```

Comment: `trackingDetaillist` is a list so you would need to loop over it. `trackingDetaillist.forEach(trackingDetail -> trackingDetail.getHistory().addAll(historyList))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a list of tracking history in EACH logistic trackings, then you have to make the List of `TrackingHistoryDTO` be a member of the class `LogisticTrackingDetailDto`.

Comment: Can you improve the answer with an example? The poster may genuinely not know how to "make the List of TrackingHistoryDTO be a member of the class LogisticTrackingDetailDto"